# how to add webcam window inside tkinter UI

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, face-recognition

i need to to add webcam window inside tkinter UI , what i actually need when the user pressed on start the webcam must appear in white box as it shown in the picture and the code down below also ive made a class that opens the webacam window and recognize faces

```
    canvans=tkinter.Canvas(pro, width =900, height = 700, borderwidth=10, relief="solid",bg="#ffffff",
                           highlightbackground="#0E6655")
    canvans.place(x=300,y=100)


    pro.mainloop()



x=Gui()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but i have query , now ive made a class called start and this class open the webcam and recognize face can you help how to implement it with code example

Comment: take a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-show-webcam-in-tkinter-window

Answer (score 1):

In comments you get link to example but I made some changes

- check if `read()` gives any frame
- use `cap.release()` after using webcam
- (PEP8) `import *` is not preferred
- (PEP8) organize code - put all functions after `import`

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions after imports

def show_frame():
   # get frame
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   
   if ret:
       # cv2 uses `BGR` but `GUI` needs `RGB`
       frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

       # convert to PIL image
       img = Image.fromarray(frame)

       # convert to Tkinter image
       photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
       
       # solution for bug in `PhotoImage`
       label.photo = photo
       
       # replace image in label
       label.configure(image=photo)  
   
   # run again after 20ms (0.02s)
   root.after(20, show_frame)

# --- main ---

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

root = tk.Tk()

# create a Label to display frames
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)  # to resize label when resize window

# start function which shows frame
show_frame()

root.mainloop()

cap.release()
```

---

BTW:

- [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- [Tkinter: Why Label doesn't display image? Bug with Garbage Collector in PhotoImage.](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkinter-why-label-doesnt-display-image-bug-with-garbage-collector-in-photoimage-GB.html)

---

**EDIT:**

The same for `Canvas`

It uses image's ID to replace `PhotoImage` on `Canvas`

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

# --- functions ---

def show_frame():
    global image_id  # inform function to assign new value to global variable instead of local variable

    # get frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
   
    if ret:
        # cv2 uses `BGR` but `GUI` needs `RGB
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # convert to PIL image
        img = Image.fromarray(frame)

        # convert to Tkinter image
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
       
        # solution for bug in `PhotoImage`
        canvas.photo = photo

        # check if image already exists
        if image_id:       
            # replace image in PhotoImage on canvas
            canvas.itemconfig(image_id, image=photo)
        else:
            # create first image on canvas and keep its ID
            image_id = canvas.create_image((0,0), image=photo, anchor='nw')
            # resize canvas
            canvas.configure(width=photo.width(), height=photo.height())
           
    # run again after 20ms (0.02s)
    root.after(20, show_frame)

# --- main ---

image_id = None  # default value at start (to create global variable)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

root = tk.Tk()

# create a Label to display frames
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# start function which shows frame
show_frame()

root.mainloop()

cap.release()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You can't imagine how grateful I am to you. I spent a lot of time trying to solve the problem for my graduation project and now it's working. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: on GitHub I have example which also use Buttons to start and stop displaying stream [furas / python-examples / cv2 / tkinter-cv2](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/tkinter-CV%20-%20with%20buttons%20to%20start%20and%20stop/main.py)

Comment: and in repo [furas / python-cv2-streams-viewer](https://github.com/furas/python-cv2-streams-viewer) I have example which creates widget to display stream from cv2 (webcam, local file, web stream) and it use this widget to display many streams at the same time.